# MUI Datagrid preProcessEditCellProps Error Message

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sass, material-ui

How can I add error message to mui preProcessEditCell?
I will like to display "Supplier Name cannot be empty" for the error text

{
field: "supplierName",
headerName: "Name",
width: 300,
editable: true,
preProcessEditCellProps: (params: GridPreProcessEditCellProps) => {
const hasError = params.props.value === '';
return { ...params.props, error: hasError};
},
},

I tried including helperText to the object being returned but it seems it(helperText) is not a valid property.